# Pass data from html form to c# webservice using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, web-services

I have a form html made using bootstrap in phpstorm, and I want to pass the information to a c# webservice using ajax. 
Bust I have some doubts in what to put in the ajax url (represented bellow).

This is my html/bootstrap form:

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="login-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Email....." class="form-username form-control" id="form-email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-text">Type Order</label>
    <input type="text" name="order" placeholder="Tipo Encomenda" class="form-text form-control" id="textbox1">
  </div>
  <span id="spnGetdet" style="font-size:x-large" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-number">Number</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="150" name="orderQuantity" placeholder="Numero Peças" class="form-number form-control" id="form-number">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-radio">Urgente</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Urgente</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Não Urgente
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitOrder">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

And this is my ajax/jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submitOrder").click(function(){
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var TextBox1 = $("#textbox1");
            TextBox1.change(function (e) {
                var Name = TextBox1.val();
                if (Name != -1) {
                    Getdet(Name);
                }else {
                    <?php echo "erro"?>;
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function Getdet(Name) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data: "{'Custname':'" + Name + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response){
                $("#spnGetdet").html(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (msg)
            {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And the last my c# webservice (this is a test, and i only want to collect the type of the order):

```
    [WebMethod]
    public String GetCustdet(string Custname)
    {
        return Custname;
    }
```

So, if i have the project(website) made in phpstorm and webservice visual studio, what do I have to put in the url of ajax to reach  the web service???

P.S: WebSite running in xampp

Comment: We have no idea where your webservice is running. How do you access it in browser? Also your submit handler and document.ready are backwards

Comment: The webservice is for running in bizagi, but for now is to run in a browser

Comment: You do NOT need this document ready event handler inside a click event handler `$(document).ready(function () {`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that, you are using MVC pattern I have given following url. You should replace controller name in [controller] place. You should replace localhost:5566 in or whatever in to [server-name].

**option 1: [GET]** http://[server-name]/[controller]/GetCustdet?Custname=Jhon
without data.

**option 2: [POST]** http://[server-name]/[controller]/GetCustdet
with **data:** '{Custname:"Jhon"}'

Otherwise, If you are using Asp.Net template to create the WebMethod then you should use the aspx page name in place the of [controller].

Alternatively, you have Route configurations to customize the URL and the data.

Comment: what is the controller?

Comment: @AdrianoMaia - WE have no idea, that is YOUR code and the URL from your site; and we have no insight into that.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I only ask what controller means in the url nothing more, of course you don't know my code.... But thank you any way